# Can I be refunded the custom duties I already paid to import a product?

Tags: united-states, refund, france

I'm living in France and I recently bought a computer in California. To be able to receive the computer I had to pay some custom duties for a value of 200€ (276.72 US$). I discovered that the computer doesn't fit my needs and I decided to return it by UPS. The company accepted the return.

Can I be refunded for custom duties I paid?

Comment: To whom did you pay customs duties? The French Customs Office when the computer was sent to you and it arrived in France? If so, you probably would have needed to fill out some paperwork for the French Customs Office when you sent the computer back; else how would they know that the computer was sent back? Did you do so?

Comment: I paid them to UPS and I plan to send it back with their services as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My French is very rusty and [douane.gouv.fr](http://www.douane.gouv.fr) is in French only. But with my rusty French I couldn't find any information that would suggest that they actually do refunds. From my experience (with other countries, not France), once a private person pays the VAT/customs - they're non-refundable (unless you're a tourist that is and can claim refund).

Comment: I'll call them next week and try to know how this stuff work. Thanks for answer